# Inequalities conditions for the followings.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

[image]

When the following inequalities are true? For for what values of w and alpha the following are true?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Well, for the first one and under the trivial condition $\,w\neq 0,1\;$ , we get

$$\frac{\sqrt{\left(w-\alpha^2\right)\left(w-\frac1{\alpha^2}\right)}}{w(1-w)}>\frac1{w(1-w)}\iff$$

$$\begin{cases}\sqrt{\left(w-\alpha^2\right)\left(w-\frac1{\alpha^2}\right)}>1&,\;\;0<w<1\\{}\\\sqrt{\left(w-\alpha^2\right)\left(w-\frac1{\alpha^2}\right)}<1&,\;\;w<0\;\vee\;w>1\end{cases}$$

In any case, the expression in the square root is non-negative, so you can square, for example in the first case:

$$(w-\alpha^2)\left(w-\frac1{\alpha^2}\right)>1\iff(w-\alpha^2)(w\alpha^2-1)>\alpha^2\ldots etc.$$

Comment: I think for condition 1, if we take w<0, then it will be true, not for 0<w<1. Since if w<0, we will get the positive answer under the square root. What you think DonAntonio about it?

Comment: @Kiran: $$w(1-w)>0\iff w(w-1)<0\iff 0<w< 1$$

Comment: why you are taking w(1-w)>0 , i do not understand this can you please provide me some more detail.

Comment: To multiply both sides of the inequality by their common divisor...but we **first** must be sure whether this is a multiplication by a positive or a negative factor!

Comment: What you suggest about the condition of \alpha what should be the condition of \alpha for this to be true ?

Comment: I don't understand you, @Kiran

Comment: I mean for what value of alpha the above inequalities will be true?